# ¿Por qué decimos "siempre" si viene del latín "sempre"?

Tags: etimología, latín, diptongos

Hoy leía un texto en italiano y me hizo gracia encontrar la palabra *sempre* en él para hablar de nuestro **siempre**. Me hizo recordar que en catalán también utilizamos *sempre*, sin la *i*. Tirando un poco del hilo vi que en todos los casos la palabra viene del latín *semper*, tal y como indica el DLE:

> [**siempre**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XpgXJJL)
>   `Del lat. semper.`

Y hay otras palabras que también tiran de esta raíz latina, como [*sempiterno*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XYqgJac), que el [Online Etymology Dictionary nos describe](https://www.etymonline.com/word/sempiternal) como:

> c. 1400, from Old French *sempiternel* "eternal, everlasting" (13c.) or directly from Late Latin *sempiternalis*, from Latin *sempiternus* "everlasting," from *semper* "always, ever" (see semper-) + *aeternus* "eternal".

Siempre vemos, pues, esta `i` ausente que de repente el castellano introdujo.

Busco en el CORPUS y encuentro textos antiquísimos, como del siglo XIII, en que se usaba:

> de boa voonta de don en Doaçon boa é vendo para *sempre* á vos Elvira añes prior do Moesteyro de Santa (...)

Pero el rastro de la palabra se pierde muy rápidamente. Eso sí, el NTLLE nos muestra en 1846 (Salvá), 1855 (Gaspar y Roig) y 1869 (Domínguez suplemento) la entrada:

> *SEMPRE* adv. ant. SIEMPRE.

O incluso menciona *semper*. Raro me parece, pues, que la palabra solamente se vea en el siglo XIII, desaparezca muchos siglos hasta llegar al siglo XIX como sinónimo antiguo de *siempre*.

Así pues: ¿qué pasó con *semper* para que se convirtiera en *siempre*?

Comment: Pues si la *e* era corta, se esperaría que acabase siendo *ie* al recaerle el acento (por eso *siete* pero *setenta*)

Answer (score 1):

En latín clásico había vocales cortas y largas. Se da por sentado que la cantidad no era la única diferencia entre los pares de vocales, sino que las cortas eran además laxas y las largas eran además tensas. "Laxo" y "tenso" son términos intencionalmente ambiguos, pero para darse una idea, es la diferencia que se da en inglés entre la *e* de *met* y la *a* de *mate* (donde también está involucrada la cantidad: la vocal de *mate* es larga), entre *bit* y *beet*, etc.

En una etapa posterior el latín comenzó a perder la distinción de cantidad, y el contraste laxo-tenso ganó protagonismo. Las vocales *e* y *o* en particular evolucionaron de forma que las *e* y *o* cortas pasaron a ser reconocidas como laxas /ɛ/ y /ɔ/, mientras que las largas pasaron a ser /e/ y /o/.

Un tiempo después comenzó un proceso de diptongación que afectó a las vocales laxas. Este proceso ocurrió en una amplia región del área romance. En el primitivo castellano hizo que /ɛ/ pasara a /i̯e/ y /ɔ/ pasara a /u̯e/ (con pasos intermedios que no conocemos).

Las vocales laxas diptongaron en castellano sólo cuando estaban acentuadas y cuando no seguía una *yod* (de ahí que en el latín *nocte*, que en este punto había pasado a pronunciarse [noi̯te], no se produjese diptongación de la *o*).

Eliminado todo rastro de la distinción de cantidad y el contraste laxo-tenso de las vocales, la diptongación quedó como una alternancia impredecible, que se hace notar sobre todo en los verbos que tenían una *e* o una *o* cortas en sus raíces latinas.

En el caso de *semper*, por lógica se debió producir la diptongación de la primera *e* al estar acentuada (como en *siempre*). Por qué aparecen textos castellanos antiguos con la forma *sempre* puede deberse a varias razones no excluyentes:

1. Que la diptongación todavía no se hubiese afianzado en la región o el dialecto particular de quien escribía;
2. Que a pesar de pronunciarse ya el diptongo, quien escribía continuaba prefiriendo una ortografía conservadora;
3. Que el diptongo se pronunciase ya, pero no fuese considerado un rasgo distintivo que meritase marcarlo.

La persistencia de la palabra *sempre* en el diccionario puede deberse a que alguna autoridad literaria o académica continuase propiciando su uso como forma conservadora más culta.

Hago notar que el texto citado parece no estar propiamente en castellano sino en gallegoportugués.

> de boa voonta de don en Doaçon boa é vendo para sempre á vos Elvira añes prior do Moesteyro de Santa (...)

En el s. XIII ya se puede hacer claramente la diferencia entre castellano y gallegoportugués, y es claramente este último el del texto, como se ve por la pérdida de la *n* en *boa* (< lat. *bona*), en *Doaçon* ("Donación"), y en *Moesteyro* ("Monasterio"). En los dialectos romances que dio origen al portugués no hubo diptongación de las vocales laxas, de manera que aquí *sempre* es el resultado regular y esperado y no una excepción o arcaísmo.

Answer (score 0):

(Mi respuesta completa en español está más abajo.)

**Summary in English, my native language:** The Spanish language had a very large *vowel shift* that left a lot of marks on the Spanish language. This Spanish vowel shift is **very obvious** in verbs like *pensar* (see below) and *moler*. When it carries the stress, the letter "e" becomes "ie" and the letter "o" becomes "ue", if it is affected by this vowel shift. Although it is obvious in conjugating verbs, it happens a lot in adjectives, nouns, and adverbs, including *siempre*. The word **diez** provides a nice example:

> Diez - Sí tiene el énfasis, así que *e* -> *ie*.
>
> Decena - No tiene el énfasis (es de-**CE**-na), así que la *e* no cambia.
>
> *Ejemplo:* "Tengo una decena de dedos."
>
> (La siguiente **sí es** una palabra válida...)
>
> Dieces - Sí tiene el énfasis, así que *e* -> *ie*.
>
> *Ejemplo:* "Voy a escribir tres dieces: Diez, 10, 0xA."
>
> (0xA es 10 en el hexadecimal.)
>
> Y con unos cognados:
>
> Decimal - No tiene el énfasis (es de-ci-**MAL**), así que la *e* no cambia.
>
> Hexadecimal - Así como *decimal* más arriba.
>
> Y unos ejemplos que **no funcionarían** en español:
>
> *(está mal)* Desimal - No. Viene del latín, debe ser **decimal**.
>
> *(está mal)* Décimal - No. Si tiene el énfasis, debe cambiar en IE. (*Décimal* sí es una palabra francesa.)
>
> *(están mal)* Diecimal, diecena - No, la E no tiene el énfasis, no debe cambiar.

Tiene mucho que ver con los verbos con E u O que tienen "diphthongization" (véase la nota 1). En esos verbos, la E u O cambia en IE o UE cuando esta vocal especial está acentuada, pero **no cambia** en el caso contrario (las sílabas tónicas están **en negrita**):

> Pen**sar**
>
> Yo **pien**so
>
> Nosotros pen**sa**mos
>
> Ustedes **pien**san

Este cambio de E u O en IE o UE no solo pasa con los verbos, también pasa con otras palabras. *Escuela* (sustantivo) pero *escolar* (adjetivo). Es UE cuando está acentuada y es O cuando no.

Este cambio ha pasado con *siempre*. Pero otras palabras que vienen de la misma fuente generalmente van a seguir la regla: E si no está acentuada, IE si está acentuada.

Advertencia: La regla no es muy estricta. Hay muchas excepciones, y la regla está cada vez menos popular. *Siempre* es una palabra más o menos antigua. También *pensar*. Palabras más recientes no cambian con tanta frecuencia, pero sí cambian a veces, especialmente cuando los hispanohablantes pueden ver una analogía, una palabra que ya existe que tiene el cambio, y la nueva palabra parece semejante.

Muchos idiomas **no tienen** esta regla de "diphthongization", por ejemplo:

Ladino (es muy fácil de entender para hispanohablantes)

Portugués

Italiano

Advertencia: Portugués e italiano han tomado prestado palabras desde el español, y por eso, a veces parece que sí tienen esta regla, pero las palabras vinieron del español. Cuando vienen del latín directamente hacia portugués o italiano, no cambian así.

**Nota 1:** "Diphthongization" (término inglés), también por otro nombre "una alternancia fonética" (término español). El término español es menos específico que el inglés porque incluye "vowel raising" como "pedir -> pido". "Diphthongization" solo refiere al proceso de cambiar una vocal (E u O) en un diptongo (o, según alguna gente, un "glide vowel"). E cambia en IE (como "glide vowel", una glosa puede ser "ye") y O cambia en UE (como "glide vowel", una glosa puede ser "we"). En Wikipedia:

[Wikipedia Española: Verbo irregular](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verbo_irregular)

[Wikipedia Inglesa: Spanish Irregular Verbs > Diphthongization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_irregular_verbs#Diphthongization)

**Nota 2:** En el siglo XIII, esta regla de "diphthongization" no existía. El ladino, que se desvió del español en el siglo XV o XVI, no tiene esta regla. En ladino, una escuela es "scola". Note que no hay una E al primer. El verbo "estar" originalmente era "star". Para conjugar "star", era "él sta". Después, añadieron la E, pero todavía tiene que tener en énfasis en la sílaba "sta". ¿Qué hicieron? **Él está.** La E solo existe para permitir el digrama "S-T", nunca debe estar acentuada.

Comment: Los comentarios sobre ladino no son [totalmente correctos](http://www.orbilat.com/Languages/Spanish-Ladino/Grammar/Ladino-Phonology.htm). Hay una variedad de realizaciones de vocales en ladino: ej. **como dices, sin diptongo:** *escola (escuela), pasensia (paciencia) preto (prieto)* | **pero también con:** | *muestro (nuestro), uerte (huerte), puedo (puedo)* |  **y además así:** | *uertolano (hortolano), pueder (poder), kerer (querer)* | **y una mezcla:** | *kuedo, kodo (codo), ken, kién (quien)* | **y desarrollos nuevos:** | *puadre (padre), muadre (madre)*

Comment: @ukemi You are 100% correct about Ladino. I am only learning Spanish (my native language is English) and I don't even pretend to know Ladino, so I learned a lot from your link, thanks. I **do** know some things about linguistics, and about the history of Ladino, and how you can use Ladino to learn things about Spanish. But you are 100% correct and thank you for teaching me. (My main point was about Spanish, and why Spanish was almost guaranteed to show this vowel shift on this Latin-based word, "siempre", due to the age of the word.)