# ¿Cómo se denomina el concepto "diphthongization" en el español?

Tags: solicitud-de-término, vocabulario-técnico, lingüística, diptongos

Distintas publicaciones del sitio ([una](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23615/1674), [dos](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/27010/1674)) hablan del concepto inglés 'diphthongization'.

Mirando en la Wikipedia, en el artículo [Vowel breaking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vowel_breaking) se explica:

> In historical linguistics, vowel breaking, vowel fracture or **diphthongization** is the change of a monophthong into a diphthong or triphthong.

Esto es (traducción libre mía):

> En la lingüística histórica, *ruptura de vocales*, *fractura de vocales* o la ***¿diptongación? ¿diptonguización?*** es el cambio de un monoptongo en un diptongo o triptongo.

Sin embargo, en la sección de otras lenguas no aparece el castellano y no acabo de ver cuál es la traducción más correcta del concepto.

Y ya que estamos, ¿alguien puede aportar una explicación más detallada de este término?

Comment: ¿Por qué diptongación no te parece adecuada?

Comment: @guifa es que no sé cuál se usa en el ámbito académico. Todas me suenan raras, así que prefiero no aventurarme :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Diptongación* es el término que se emplea en castellano:

> #### [diptongación](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DqSMsYB)
>
> 1. `f.` *Fon.* Acción y efecto de diptongar.

---

Puedes ver en [Google Scholar (es): "diptongación"](https://scholar.google.es/scholar?hl=es&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=diptongaci%C3%B3n) que el término sí se usa en el ámbito académico:

- *La diptongación en leonés*, D Catalán, ÁG de Fuentes (1954)
- *Diptongación castellana y diptongación románica*, D ALonso (1962)
- *De la escritura al habla: la diptongación de O breve tónica en el Alto Aragón*, A Vàrvaro (1991)
- *Aspectos fonéticos de la diptongación del rumeno*, F Sánchez Miret (2013)

etc

---

Según [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=diptongaci%C3%B3n&year_start=1860&year_end=2008&corpus=21&smoothing=3), se ha utilizado desde finales del siglo XIX:

[image]

Primera entrada en un diccionario: 1884 ACADEMIA USUAL

Comment: Oh, ¿y alguna explicación a su menor uso actual según la gráfica?

Comment: @fedorqui no sé - puede ser una peculiaridad de los textos muestreados por Google, ya que la palabra 'diptongo' sí misma muestra el mismo 'bache' y disminución: [**diptongación** vs **diptongo**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=diptongación%2C+diptongo&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21&smoothing=3)